# Replicating the elongated drop cap from The Doves Press Bible

Tags: typography, drop-cap

The Doves Press was one of the major players in the early British private press movement, hand-printing books in Hammersmith that were known for the absence of any illustrations and a focus on the aesthetics of beautiful type. Below is the famous first page from the Doves Press Bible.

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to replicate this "I" that extends downwards to the height of the text? I find this quite interesting because there are several letters that could elegantly be extended vertically by stretching the vertical strokes of the letterform while leaving the proportions of other parts unstretched (I, J, H, E, P, L, F, T, Y, U, M).

[image]

Comment: Not uninteresting but too many questions. Chances are this will be closed as "needs more focus". I would suggest to ask separate questions.

Comment: the drop caps in the margin are easy enough, 4 lines of caps, I'd do by hand choosing where to capitalise based on the line breaks.  That leaves extending the letter full height, which probably means re-creating it in tikz or similar, unless the font has built in extended variants (but I'm not buying it just to find out)

Comment: @campa I removed one of the questions. Now there's only really one question, which is how do I recreate these drop caps in LaTeX? I also edited to be clear why I think this is a bit more involved than a simple drop cap.

Comment: These drop caps and titling caps must have been specially made, and no such characters are provided in the revival. Note how thin and shapely the serifs are, quite unlike the slabs in the font. I tried reproducing the page from Genesis, and the `I` became impossibly heavy. It’s not just a matter of stretching the character mechanically; it’s a work of art.

Comment: Possibly related, possibly not: If you actually intend to print books like that (to paper), and you hope to use print-on-demand technology, be aware that many such services will reject books with artistic presentation. The reason is that the workers, who have never seen your book before and may never see it again, cannot tell whether the printed pages (with asymmetrical margins, etc.) are correct or not.

Comment: @Ubiquitous This remains many questions. The proof of this is that you have an answer to just one of them. You might think of them as similar, but they involve very different problems. That they all involve drop capitals is really irrelevant.

Comment: @cfr Okay. I edited this to a single question and posted the rest separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should not use Latin modern, but you can clip an "I" into top middle and bottom and stretch the middle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,trimclip}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\leavevmode\llap{%}
\color{red}%
\smash{%
\offinterlineskip
\fontsize{100pt}{0pt}\selectfont
\vtop to \dimexpr\textheight-30pt{
\kern-30pt
\hbox{\clipbox{0pt 6pt 0pt 0pt}{I}}
\kern-50pt
\leaders
\hbox{\clipbox{0pt 6pt 0pt 6pt}{I}}
\vfill
\kern-50pt
\hbox{\clipbox{0pt 0pt 0pt 6pt}{I}}
}}\kern-1pt}%
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\textcolor{red}{\MakeUppercase{n the beginning}}}\\
God created the heaven and the earth.
\P And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.
\P And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.
\P And God saw the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness.
\P And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And the evening and the morning were the first day.
\P And God said, Let there be a firmament in the midst of the waters, and let it divide the waters from the waters.
\P And God made the firmament, and divided the waters which were under the firmament from the waters which were above the firmament: and it was so.
\P And God called the firmament Heaven. And the evening and the morning were the second day.
\P And God said, Let the waters under the heaven be gathered together unto one place, and let the dry land appear: and it was so.
\P And God called the dry land Earth; and the gathering together of the waters called he Seas: and God saw that it was good.
\P And God said, Let the earth bring forth grass, the herb yielding seed, and the fruit tree yielding fruit after his kind, whose seed is in itself, upon the earth: and it was so.
\P And the earth brought forth grass, and herb yielding seed after his kind, and the tree yielding fruit, whose seed was in itself, after his kind: and God saw that it was good.
\P And the evening and the morning were the third day.
\P And God said, Let there be lights in the firmament of the heaven to divide the day from the night; and let them be for signs, and for seasons, and for days, and years:
\P And let them be for lights in the firmament of the heaven to give light upon the earth: and it was so.
\P And God made two great lights; the greater light to rule the day, and the lesser light to rule the night: he made the stars also.
\P And God set them in the firmament of the heaven to give light upon the earth,
\P And to rule over the day and over the night, and to divide the light from the darkness: and God saw that it was good.
\P And the evening and the morning were the fourth day.
\P And God said, Let the waters bring forth abundantly the moving creature that hath life, and fowl that may fly above the earth in the open firmament of heaven.
\P And God created great whales, and every living creature that moveth, which the waters brought forth abundantly, after their kind, and every winged fowl after his kind: and God saw that it was good.
\P And God blessed them, saying, Be fruitful, and multiply, and fill the waters in the seas, and let fowl multiply in the earth.
\P And the evening and the morning were the fifth day.
\P And God said, Let the earth bring forth the living creature after his kind, cattle, and creeping thing, and beast of the earth after his kind: and it was so.
\P And God made the beast of the earth after his kind, and cattle after their kind, and every thing that creepeth upon the earth after his kind: and God saw that it was good.
\P And God said, Let us make man in our image, after our likeness: and let them have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over the cattle, and over all the earth, and over every creeping thing that creepeth upon the earth.
\P So God created man in his own image, in the image of God created he him; male and female created he them.
\P And God blessed them, and God said unto them, Be fruitful, and multiply, and replenish the earth, and subdue it: and have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over every living thing that moveth upon the earth.
\P And God said, Behold, I have given you every herb bearing seed, which is upon the face of all the earth, and every tree, in the which is the fruit of a tree yielding seed; to you it shall be for meat.
\P And to every beast of the earth, and to every fowl of the air, and to every thing that creepeth upon the earth, wherein there is life, I have given every green herb for meat: and it was so.
\P And God saw every thing that he had made, and, behold, it was very good. And the evening and the morning were the sixth day.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

https://www.overleaf.com/read/cgzwbzwzxbng